# JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode() adds extra child for arrays

Tags: c#, serialization

I am using JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode() to serialize a xml node:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml.ToString());
jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

here is an example xml array

```
<cars>
   <car>
     <id>0001</id>
   </car>
   <car>
     <id>0002</id>
   </car>
</cars>
```

this would become:

```
{
   "cars" : {
       "car" : [{
          "carId" : "0001"
       }, {
          "carId" : "0002"
       }]
   }
}
```

Is there a way to serialize the array like this?

```
{
   "cars" : [{
          "carId" : "0001"
       }, {
          "carId" : "0002"
       }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `XElement` is a better choice while dealing with xml, as its newer.
I wrote a quick code and tested, it works all good, may be its not well optimized and ideal but its here to show you the way to go, hope it will help.

```
var xml = @"<cars><car><id>0001</id></car><car><id>0002</id></car></cars>";

XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);

var cars = new
{
    cars = (from c in doc.Descendants("car")
            select new { carid = c.Element("id").Value }
            ).ToList()
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cars);

Console.WriteLine("Json: {0}", json.ToString());
```

just copy paste in your console app and see if that's what you were looking for.